# highcharts context menu hidden for small charts

Tags: highcharts

I am migrating a dashboard type screen to [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and would like to use the default context menu (for exporting various image formats and printing the chart).

The problem is that a lot of these charts are small gauge type charts and the context menu gets hidden when charts get below a certain size, mainly due to the fact that the context menu appears above the button for small charts size.

Is there anyway to make the context menu always appear below the button? I know I can limit the options and this will solve the problem but I would ideally like to use the default options list. Also I don't really want to have to calculate positions and move it myself.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MnYw/1/)

```
see code at jsfiddle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following styles to the context menu.

```
.highcharts-contextmenu {
    bottom: auto !important;
    top: 5px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/xBUXK/)**

Comment: Was hoping for some setting to do this but this works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work for your situation, but have you considered using their pie chart with the legend at the bottom?

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend

Comment: Sorry I mentioned the wrong chart type (I've updated the question), I meant a gauge chart (though the same issue is present for other chart types) so this won't change things as I don't have a legend. Thanks anyway though.