# HighCharts: context menu hidden for small charts

Tags: highcharts

My problem is exactly the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800674/highcharts-context-menu-hidden-for-small-charts). The context menu gets hidden when charts get below a certain size. The accepted answer:

```
.highcharts-contextmenu {
    bottom: auto !important;
    top: 5px;
}
```

works to make the menu downwards. But it is still hidden if the chart is small. Something like this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xBUXK/14/).

Could anybody please help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [highcharts context menu hidden for small charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800674/highcharts-context-menu-hidden-for-small-charts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite z-index and overflow on highcharts-1 container

http://jsfiddle.net/xBUXK/16/

```
#highcharts-0 {
    overflow:visible!important;
    z-index:1!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastian-Bochan. But the id #highcharts-0 seems auto-generated. I have more than one charts. How to set the context menu of all of them? In my application, my charts are within a div with z-index 1000. I set the #highcharts-0 z-index to be 1001, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I modified Sebastian Bochans answer to this and it worked:

```
.highcharts-container {
   overflow:visible!important;
   z-index:1!important;
}
```